# Is it possible to download GPX another coordinate system except WGS(GCS) with GPS Tool on QGIS1.8.0?

Tags: qgis, gps, coordinate-system

I got GPS data with using bessel1841 as coordinate system.
When I download GPX data on GPS tool, it is automatically treated as WGS84.

Can I use another coordinate system when I download GPX on GPS tool.

It is impossible to convert data from WGS84 to Bessel1841 on QGIS as far as I know - but I asked here: [Is it possible to convert data from WGS84 to Bessel1841?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50481/is-it-possible-to-convert-data-from-wgs84-to-bessel1841)

Answer (score 1):

GPX is always in WGS84:

> "GPX schema version 1.1 - For more information on GPX and this schema,
>   visit http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp
>
> GPX uses the following conventions: all coordinates are relative to
>   the WGS84 datum.  All measurements are in metric units."

[From http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd]

The aspect about importing into QGIS has been addressed in other questions, so I won't try to address that here.